# How to divide feature and scenario in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I need to manage some uses in system, so user management is a feature , and add/delete user is a Scenario?  I want to know one principle to design them, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

```
# user-mgmt.feature
Feature: User management

    Scenario: User addition
        Given that no user named 'doe' exists
        When I create an account for 'doe'
        Then the list of users will include a record for 'doe'

    Scenario: Deletion of non-existing user
        Given that no user named 'doe' exists
        When I remove the account 'doe'
        Then I get an error message
```

Have also a look at [how to create more concise features](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/cucumber-more-advanced/) and the [git examples](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/examples).

My advice is to just create a feature file and run `cucumber`. It will tell you what to do.